# How can I keep onClickOutside() method disabled until I use onClick()?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, onclick

When I click on my  element with an event listener I supposed to get my popup shown, which works just fine until I introduce onClickOutside(). Using [ng-click-outside](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-click-outside)

```js
export class Component {
  private isPopupDisplayed: boolean = false;

  onClick() {
    console.log('Clicked');
    this.isPopupDisplayed = true;
  }
  
  onClickedOutside(event) {
    this.isPopupDisplayed = false;
  }
  
}
```

```css
.popup{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 200px;
  height: 94px;
  background-color: $secondary-color;
  left: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  margin: 12px;
  border: 1px solid $modal-border-color;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);

  li:hover {
    background-color: $accent-color;
  }

  li {
    padding-top: 5px;
    height: 32px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="isPopupDisplayed" >
        <ul class="popup" (clickOutside)="onClickedOutside($event)">
            <li><a>My Details</a></li>
            <li><a>Sign out</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>

    <div class="presenter-menu_avatar" (click)="onClick()" >
        <img [src]="avatarUrl">
    </div>
```

When I am trying to introduce onClickOutside() method, I can see that both methods are triggered at the same time as my popup still not there and that automatically triggers not even showing it up.

My aim is to simply show the popup when onClick() and hide it when clicked outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Add stopPropagation event in  click function

```
  onClick(event) {
    event.stopPropagation()
    console.log('Clicked');
    this.isPopupDisplayed = true;
  }




<div class="presenter-menu_avatar" (click)="onClick($event)" >
    <img [src]="avatarUrl">
</div>
```

Comment: It works, kudos to you! I would really appreciate if you would be able to quickly explain what exactly does it do to make it work?

Comment: It will fire both event because  `<div class="presenter-menu_avatar" (click)="onClick()" >` outside of onClickedOutside directive. And`event.stopPropogation()` method just stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements